# Datepicker jQuery - something missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I want to change date format, in date "from - to" feature, in classic jQuery datepicker.
My code is:

```
$(function() {
  $("#from").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
    }
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
      $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
  }); $("#to").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
  }
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: true,
  numberOfMonths: 3,
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
  }
});
```

But it's not even working.. Whats wrong? Thank you, and hot regards!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that periods are considered a valid format, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong here. Can you use hyphens or slashes?

```
{ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" }
```

OR

```
{ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }
```

If these won't work, there's a list of predefined ones in the documentation too. Take a look here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Comment: I got second datepicker to different function - $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy" }).val()
     }); - 
and it works ;) with periods. But I cannot include dateformat, to from to datepicker.

Comment: ah, fair enough. Try adding a comma after the closing curly brace

{ dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy" },